# Laravel Model renaming MySQL table to plural on query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using a model to query a remote MySQL DB and when I run the query, Laravel is trying to connect to the plural version of the table that I need it to connect to. The table's name is `activity` and the error I get is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'health.activities' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `activities`)
```

I just built the model for this using `artisan make:model Activity` so I am not sure what is going on. Here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Activity extends Model
{
    private $activity;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->activity = DB::connection('mysql_remote')->table('activity');
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function getDashboard()
    {
        $data = [
            'page_title' => 'Dashboard',
            'users'      => User::getUser(),
            'test' => Activity::get(),
        ];

        return view('dashboard.dashboard', $data);
    }
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Models expect the table to be named the plural of the name of the Model, in this case the plural of `Activitiy` is `activities` which is the table name it expects.  If it's different, you need to add a `table` property to set the name of the table.

In your model, add the following...

```
protected $table = 'activity';
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your help and your explanation!